# Error #Value! in Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function Heston(Actualvol As Double, m As Double, theta As Double, col As Double, nSim As Long, nStep As Long) As Double
    Dim FinalVol As Double, VT As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer, dt As Double, sum As Double

    dt = 1 / 252

    For i = 1 To nSim
        For j = 0 To nStep
            Actualvol = Actualvol + m * (theta - Actualvol) * dt + col * Sqr(Actualvol) * Application.NormInv(Rnd(), 0, 1) * Sqr(dt)
        Next

        sum = sum + Actualvol
    Next

    FinalVol = Sqr(sum)
    Heston = FinalVol / Sqr(nSim)
End Function
```

Please check this why it shows #Value! in the ExcelSheet ?

Comment: Hi Martin, Its not clear why this shows this error ?

Comment: Are you passing all the six arguments in the UDF?

Comment: Are the two questions you've asked not duplicates?  They're questions based on the same piece of code -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120311/duplication-error-in-current-scope-vba-code

Comment: Could be square root of a negative. Is the function called with negative dt, Actualvol, or nSim? Could the `Actualvol = ...` line drive Actualvol negative during execution of the the iteration loops?

Comment: They are the same type pf codes but not exactly the same Darren.

Comment: I got it fixed. There was just a line  missing to be added more .i.e. initial value of Actualvol for each simulation.Thanks all.